# Accessing an element in a 2D array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, tile

I'm writing a platform game in c++ and using a tiled map to build the world.

The map contains values which are assigned tiles:

eg of a 2D array:

```
int map[4][4]={
    {1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 0, 0, 1},
    {1, 0, 0, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1}, };
```

I create a sprite in a similar way: `int sprite[1][1]={ {2} };`

My question is, how do you access a specific tile or element in a 2D array **?**

I read this [post(3rd post down)](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/18315/) and wondering whether 2D arrays aren't the best to use.

My sprite always stays centred to the window and upon key presses my world moves behind him.

I want to collide with certain tiles, therefore need some interaction between my sprite 2D array tile and my Map 2D array...

Also as it stands, I can walk out of the map because I haven't coded it otherwise. How would I go about this **?** Ideally I want to stop him leaving the map, then I can integrate the collision with that.

Below is a screenshot of what things look like(but with a bigger map than shown above):
[image: reanimation platformer]

Comment: `int sprite[1][1]={ {2} };` This is a 2D array with only one element in it. Why do you want that? What does the 2 represent?

Comment: I tried drawing a sprite using an `OpenGL quad` but it didn't show on screen and also wouldn't show the tiles when I do so. I used a 2D array for the sprite to solve the problem. Plus I figured its easier to keep the sprite a tile as its easier to interact a tile with a tile than a tile with a custom rectangle. The `2` represents the value of which `Tile2` gets assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have:

```
int array[4][4];
```

I can access elements by:

```
array[a_num][also_a_num]
```

where i and j are valid indices.

Usually when I want something like this I just use a 1d array and some math.

```
int height = a_num;
int width = also_a_num;
int amap[height * width];
int x_pos,y_pos;
int value = amap[y_pos*width + x_pos];
```

You can check bounds on x_pos and y_pos pretty easily.

As to the collision, you could try an array of structs.

```
struct tile{
  bool walkable;
  int type;
};

tile amap[height*width];
```

Comment: This is a really good answer. Thanks :D I will give it ago.
And yes, that post/forum I linked in the question uses a 1D array too. Thanks for your time, its much appreciated.